# While running the docker image docker build-arg values are not showing on console

Tags: docker

I have created a `Dockerfile` shown below:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER  ravat  
CMD echo "Hello"
ARG jam_url
ENV jam_url=$jam_url
ENTRYPOINT echo "This is, $jam_url" 
ENV name Ravat Tailor  
ENTRYPOINT echo "Hello, $name"
```

I build the image with the following `docker build` command:

```
docker build -t dockerdemo --build-arg jam_url=mydomain .
```

after that I run the image:

```
docker run dockerdemo
```

and get the following output:

> Hello, Ravat Tailor

My problem is: why are `jam_url` and `Hello` not printing to the console?

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. Only the last ENTRYPOINT instruction is used when running an image. If there are more than one, the last is selected. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint
2. The same goes for CMD https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd
   And if there's a CMD and ENTRYPOINT instruction, it'll choose the ENTRYPOINT instruction instead.

This will do what you're trying to achieve:

`FROM ubuntu
ARG jam_url
ENV jam_url=$jam_url
ENV name Ravat Tailor
ENTRYPOINT echo "This, $jam_url\nHello $name"`

Comment: Thanks, +1
It is working fine
one more question like, If I want to provide build argument through maven docker image build how can I do that?